# Filter content based on two dropdown values

Tags: javascript

I have two dropdowns which function as filters for job postings.

```
const type = ['all', 'fulltime', 'parttime'];
const department = ['all', 'engineering', 'design'];
```

Here is the data I'm trying to filter (by default both the dropdowns have a value of `all`)

```
let jobs = [
  { 
    role: 'a',
    department: 'engineering',
    type: 'fulltime'
  },
  { 
    role: 'b',
    department: 'design',
    type: 'parttime'
  },
  { 
    role: 'c',
    department: 'engineering',
    type: 'parttime'
  }
]
```

Both filters can be active at the same time, thus filtering two-levels.
eg: Department Filter Selected: 'Engineering' ([2] returns array of 2 objects) => user selects second filter =>  Type Filter Selected: 'fulltime' ([1] returns array of 1 object)

All clicking `all` of a filter, it should reset that particular filter only.

Here is what I tried, can't seem to wrap my head around a reasonable solution.

```
const filterJobs = () => {
    const { department, type} = filters; //filters selected by user

    if(department === 'all'){
      return;
    } else{
      filteredJobs = jobs.filter((job)=>job.department === department)
    }

    if(type === 'all'){
      return;
    } else{
      filteredJobs = jobs.filter((job)=>job.type === type)
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use just a single `.filter`, and in the callback, perform both checks for `department` and `type` in separate expressions:

```
jobs.filter((job) => (
  (department === 'all' || job.department === department) &&
  (type === 'all' || job.type === type)
));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const allFields ='all';
const filteredJobs = jobs.filter(job => 
    (department === allFields || department === job.department) &&
    (type === allFields || type === job.type)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one loop:

```js
const jobs = [
  { role: 'a', department: 'engineering', type: 'fulltime' },
  { role: 'b', department: 'design', type: 'parttime' },
  { role: 'c', department: 'engineering', type: 'parttime' }
];

const filterJobs = (filters) => {
  let { department='all', type='all' } = filters;
  return jobs.filter(job => 
    (department==='all' || job.department === department) &&
    (type==='all' || job.type === type)
  );
}

console.log( filterJobs({ department: 'all', type: 'fulltime' }) );
console.log( filterJobs({ department: 'all', type: 'parttime' }) );
console.log( filterJobs({ department: 'engineering', type: 'parttime' }) );
```